# Image storage/search web application

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, search, image, sharing

I work for a multimedia department of the government and we have a lot of images that we would like to share with others departments.

Here some information:

- We have around 20TB of images and photos to share.
- We already have a windows 2008 environment running .net mvc web applications.
- We already have a mssql cluster in place.
- We have plenty of storage space on our web servers farm.
- We have a 20mb/s connection available.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel so i would like to know if someone know a web project that already exist that would meet ours needs.

Since we always develop on .net mvc and use mssql I would prefer to stick with these technologies.

Would it be better to start from scratch?

- If yes do you have some recommendation for:
- The storage(file vs database)
- The thumbnail creation (our original picture are often huge ie: several GB)
- The search in filename, metadata(photoshop/indesing),etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of quick ideas off the top of my head:  First Microsoft SharePoint Foundation or Windows Sharepoint Services (Sharepoint Foundation is the newest incarnation of the software).  Or an open source .net portal application DotNetNuke.  Both of these have far more functionality than you're asking about here, but both will easily do what you want as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sharepoint look promising but I could not find anything specific on image search engine, they seem to focus on the pdf, words, excell search side.